# How to solve ADMOB PLUS error with Appery.io IONIC implementation

Tags: typescript, cordova-admob, appery.io

I'm trying to implement ADMOB-Plus cordova plugin with an sample test APP.
After follwing the instructions from  https://docs.appery.io/docs/ionic-5-google-admob-plug-in-tutorial. I'm gettiong compiler errors.Earlier I have seen this implementation working.Now I'm getting the following Error LOG FILE:

***** sh

```
+ ionic integrations enable cordova
[INFO] Integration cordova already enabled.
+ npm install
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

> nice-napi@1.0.2 install **********/app/node_modules/nice-napi
> node-gyp-build


> esbuild@0.15.5 postinstall **********/app/node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild
> node install.js


> esbuild@0.15.13 postinstall **********/app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild
> node install.js


> core-js@3.26.1 postinstall **********/app/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/android-arm@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/android-arm@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-loong64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"loong64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-android-64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-android-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-android-64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-android-arm64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-android-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-android-arm64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-darwin-64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-darwin-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-darwin-64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-32@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-32@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-mips64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"mips64el"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-ppc64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ppc64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-riscv64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"riscv64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-s390x@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-s390x):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-s390x@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"s390x"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-netbsd-64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-netbsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-netbsd-64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"netbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-openbsd-64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-openbsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-openbsd-64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"openbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-sunos-64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-sunos-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-sunos-64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-32@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-windows-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-32@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-windows-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-arm64@0.15.13 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-windows-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-arm64@0.15.13: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-loong64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"loong64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-android-64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-android-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-android-64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-android-arm64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-android-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-android-arm64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-darwin-64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-darwin-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-darwin-64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-32@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-32@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-mips64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"mips64el"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-ppc64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ppc64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-riscv64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"riscv64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-s390x@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-linux-s390x):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-s390x@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"s390x"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-netbsd-64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-netbsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-netbsd-64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"netbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-openbsd-64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-openbsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-openbsd-64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"openbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-sunos-64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-sunos-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-sunos-64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-32@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-windows-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-32@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-windows-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-arm64@0.15.5 (node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/esbuild-windows-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-arm64@0.15.5: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @agm/core@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @agm/core@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@14.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^14.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 1276 packages from 677 contributors and audited 1320 packages in 79.423s

211 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
***** echo

***** echo
Installing plugin admob-plus-cordova:1.25.0
***** sh
+ cd app
+ ionic cordova plugin add ../2cc7b9c9-3bf0-44d3-be02-3010b9014685-plugins/admob-plus-cordova --save --variable 'ADMOB_APP_ID= ca-app-pub-3076896849214312~8657459220'
✔ Creating ./www directory for you - done!
> cordova plugin add ../2cc7b9c9-3bf0-44d3-be02-3010b9014685-plugins/admob-plus-cordova --variable "ADMOB_APP_ID= ca-app-pub-3076896849214312~8657459220"
Adding admob-plus-cordova to package.json
***** echo

***** echo
Installing plugin cordova-plugin-resource-generator:0.1.0
***** sh
+ cd app
+ ionic cordova plugin add ../2cc7b9c9-3bf0-44d3-be02-3010b9014685-plugins/cordova-plugin-resource-generator --save
> cordova plugin add ../2cc7b9c9-3bf0-44d3-be02-3010b9014685-plugins/cordova-plugin-resource-generator
Adding cordova-plugin-resource-generator to package.json
***** echo

***** sh
+ ionic cordova platform add android@10.1.0 ---no-interactive --confirm
> cordova platform add android@10.1.0
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@10.1.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: io.appery.project776299
    Name: MYAPP2
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-30
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@10.1.0
Installing "admob-plus-cordova" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-resource-generator" for android
Generating icons and splashscreens for Android
Temporary directory is /tmp/cordova-resD65r3T
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview". Adding it to the project
Generated 18 resources for Android
Wrote to config.xml
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to package.json
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-device". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-device to package.json
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-splashscreen to package.json
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-statusbar to package.json
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard to package.json
Discovered plugin "cordova-sqlite-ext". Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-sqlite-ext" for android
installing external dependencies via npm
for package name: cordova-sqlite-ext
npm install of external dependencies ok
Adding cordova-sqlite-ext to package.json
***** echo

***** echo
Building debug application
***** sh
+ ionic cordova build android
> ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
- @ionic/storage [es2015/esm2015] (git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage.git)
- @ionic-native/core [module/esm5] (git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.git)
- @ionic-native/ionic-webview [module/esm5] (git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.git)
- @ionic-native/device [module/esm5] (git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.git)
- @ionic-native/splash-screen [module/esm5] (git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.git)
- @ionic-native/status-bar [module/esm5] (git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.git)
- @ionic-native/keyboard [module/esm5] (git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.git)
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Warning: **********/app/node_modules/@admob-plus/ionic/ngx/index.js depends on 'admob-plus-cordova'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: **********/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ionic-storage.js depends on 'localforage'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: **********/app/node_modules/@ionic/storage/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ionic-storage.js depends on 'localforage-cordovasqlitedriver'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: **********/app/node_modules/@tinkoff/ng-dompurify/fesm2015/tinkoff-ng-dompurify.js depends on 'dompurify'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: **********/app/src/app/scripts/apperyio/apperyio_restservice.ts depends on 'rxjs/add/operator/map'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: **********/app/src/app/scripts/apperyio/apperyio_restservice.ts depends on 'x2js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: **********/app/src/app/scripts/apperyio/entityapi_service.ts depends on 'lodash'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies



Error: node_modules/@admob-plus/ionic/ngx/index.d.ts:2:112 - error TS2724: '"admob-plus-cordova"' has no exported member named 'NativeAdOptions'. Did you mean 'NativeActions'?

2 import { AdMob as IAdMob, BannerAd as IBannerAd, BannerAdOptions, InterstitialAd as IInterstitialAd, MobileAd, NativeAdOptions, NativeActions, RewardedAd as IRewardedAd, RewardedAdOptions, RewardedInterstitialAd as IRewardedInterstitialAd, NativeAd as INativeAd, RewardedInterstitialAdOptions, TrackingAuthorizationStatus } from 'admob-plus-cordova';
                                                                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
        
        ng run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Appry.io does not give support for Plugins so, I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I have also asked this to  Chat CPT but I didn't get the answer to my questions. So the question is How to solve this issue?